# Odd axis label behaviour after setting xlim in pyramid.plot [plotrix]

Tags: r, plot, stacked-chart, plotrix

I'm trying to make an "opposing stacked bar chart" and have found `pyramid.plot` from the `plotrix` package seems to do the job. (I appreciate `ggplot2` will be the go-to solution for some of you, but I'm hoping to stick with `base` graphics on this one.)

Unfortunately it seems to do an odd thing with the x axis, when I try to set the limits to non integer values. If I let it define the limits automatically, they are integers and in my case that just leaves too much white space. But defining them as `xlim=c(1.5,1.5)` produces the odd result below.

If I understand correctly from the documentation, there is no way to pass on additional graphical parameters to e.g. suppress the axis and add it on later, or let alone define the tick points etc. Is there a way to make it more flexible?

Here is a minimal working example used to produce the plot below.

```
require(plotrix)
set.seed(42)
pyramid.plot(cbind(runif(7,0,1),
                   rep(0,7),
                   rep(0,7)),
             cbind(rep(0,7),
                   runif(7,0,1),
                   runif(7,0,1)),
             top.labels=NULL, 
             gap=0,
             labels=rep("",7),
             xlim=c(1.5,1.5))
```

[image]

Just in case it is of interest to anyone else, I'm not doing a population pyramid, but rather attempting a stacked bar chart with some of the values negative. The code above includes a 'trick' I use to make it possible to have a different number of sets of bars on each side, namely adding empty columns to the matrix, hopefully someone will find that useful - so sorry the working example is not as minimal as it could have been!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the x axis labels using `laxlab` and `raxlab` creates a continuous axis:

```
pyramid.plot(cbind(runif(7,0,1),
                   rep(0,7),
                   rep(0,7)),
             cbind(rep(0,7),
                   runif(7,0,1),
                   runif(7,0,1)),
             top.labels=NULL, 
             gap=0,
             labels=rep("",7),
             xlim=c(1.5,1.5),
             laxlab = seq(from = 0, to = 1.5, by = 0.5),
             raxlab=seq(from = 0, to = 1.5, by = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: How I ever managed to miss that, I have no idea.. Am I right in assuming though that I can't play with the ticks etc? It would be nice e.g. if `xaxt="n"` worked.

Comment: Many plot functions, which use the `base` R plot machinery, have the `...` argument. For example, `plot.default`: "other graphical parameters (see `par`", or `?plot.lm` "other parameters to be passed through to plotting functions.". `pyramid.plot` doesn't seem to have that possibility, i.e. you can't use `par` arguments in this function.

Comment: Yes, luckily it turns out the whole pyramid.plot source code is actually quite straightforward, so I've been able to use it to rewrite the function for my purposes. It uses `plot.default` and `rect`, both of which have the `...` argument. So I can suppress the axis and add my own, also change e.g the border colour of the stacks etc.